# Can we modify error responses from AWS Cognito?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I want to modify error responses from Cognito in case of an Invalid Username and password. Is there a way to perform that?
I am following this link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html. But unable to find any example.